# How to determine the type of an array element?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector

I can't get the type of an element. This solution returns a reference to element type.

```
int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
using arrElemType = decltype(*arr);
vector<arrElemType> vec(std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr));
```

Comment: Type traits to the rescue!

Comment: You can use `typeid` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf39xec%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Cyber: That's a non-standard, non-portable precursor to `decltype`.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but since C++ 17 there is CTAD where you don't need the  type specified. That won't help for all cases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following

```
using arrElemType = std::remove_reference<decltype( *arr )>::type;
```

or

```
typedef std::remove_reference<decltype( *arr )>::type arrElemType;
```

You need to include header `<type_traits>`

Comment: I would go all the way and `std::decay` if I plan on storing it.

Answer (score 17):

The standard way in C++11 and above is to use [`std::remove_all_extents`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_all_extents).

```
#include <type_traits>

int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
using arrElemType = std::remove_all_extents<decltype(arr)>::type;
vector<arrElemType> vec(std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since C++ 11, when only array type is given (not the array variable):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
using array_entry_t = typename std::remove_reference<decltype( std::declval<T>()[0] )>::type;
```

Full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
using array_entry_t = typename std::remove_reference<decltype( std::declval<T>()[0] )>::type;

int main()
{
    using MyArr = char[3];
    std::cout<< typeid(              MyArr ).name() << std::endl; // Prints e.g: A3_c
    std::cout<< typeid(array_entry_t<MyArr>).name() << std::endl; // Prints e.g: c

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My aim here is to give it a go without type_traits. With C++20, we can have lambda in `decltype()`, so this code works with GCC10.2 flag `-std=c++20`

```cpp
int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
using arrElemType = decltype([&](){return arr[0];}()); 
vector<arrElemType> vec(std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr));
```

### Pitfall

The below attempt was my first answer which got negative feedback. I kept it for educational purposes so others don't fall into this because of implicit integral type promotion:

```
uint8_t a;
auto x = +a; // x is int, not uint8_t
auto y = a+a; // y is int, not uint8_t
```

So while the example below works, if we change the type of array to `uint8_t` it will still create `vector<int>`.
OK, now read it:

If `+` operator is defined for elements:

```cpp
int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
using arrElemType = decltype(+arr[0]); // + is the key
vector<arrElemType> vec(std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr));
```

- `<type_traits>` header is not needed.
- `+arr[0]` expression turns to *prvalue*, which decltype deduces as T.
- `decltype(arr[0])` gives T& which is not desirable here.
- The array elements are not accessed within decltype, so it doesn't matter if you use `arr[1000]`.

Comment: I think that works in this case because the input is an array of integers. The `+` is likely to convert the type to `int` which is probably undesirable (it could be an array of `uint8_t`).

Comment: Thanks @AlexisWilke, very good point, I update my answer.